# Updating with record type as null

Tags: configuration

We have contacts with recordtype x, y and blank. I would want to update contacts with recordtype x and blank to y using a process builder. 
[image]So, in the formula for the process builder, I used the OR condition - (OR[Contact].RecordType.Id =<18 digit ID>, ISBLANK([Contact].Record type.Id)). Also tried with recordtype <>y. Have also tried using the condition.

It works when the record type is not null. But when I try updating a record with a null record type, it errors.

Answer (score 0):

Once you create custom record type for any object, *blank* record type is "Master".

Try following, hope this helps:[image]

UPD: The capture is slightly not clear. Check if you can create formula
[Contact].RecordType.Name = 'Master'

Comment: No, this didn't help either. Get the same error - "Give your Salesforce admin these details. <b>An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow</b><br>An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the flow. Please contact your system administrator for more information. Error ID: 778148046-475352 (-1077296319)" and this is only when I try to update a record with a null record type. If the record type has a value, then the update works

Comment: The point is Record Type cannot be null. Once you have custom record type, if user does not define record type, salesforce assigns default value for user's profile.

Comment: Yeah, true. But I can't seem to update such records with a custom record type with the process builder.

Comment: Unfortunately Master record type is not accessible, and there is no way to revert record type value to its Id

Comment: So, it seems like when cross referencing fields, a not blank condition needs to be checked. I was cross referencing an account field w/o the check. Now, it works (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000212174&language=en_US&type=1)